# How to enable/configure SOAP over JMS using JAX-WS?

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, websphere-8

I have a WebService exposed using JAX-WS. I need to alter it's binding so it can work using JMS transport.

I'm running WebSphere 8.5.5, w/ java-ee version 6, and Eclipse.

---

*I've been looking all around the web for a comprehensive guide on how to do that, and the best link I found was [this](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/twbs_soapjmstransportwbs.html?lang=en). It requires me to run **endptEnabler**, and the tool is informing me that I have no Web Services in my ear, which I certainly do. I also found [this](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WSGET/jax-ws-jmstransport.htm#WSGET3560), which seems to apply to WebLogic only. A bonus question is: is it really that hard/obscure? Should I give up on this?*

Comment: Why do you want to complicate things?

Comment: @RajaAnbazhagan sorry, *why* am I complicating things?

Comment: IMHO I wouldnt suggest you to sandwitch JMS. A straightforward JMS implementation would perform well.

Comment: The following link a tutorial using RAD. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/tutorials/0903_adams/index.html. All complexity of implementation are correct WSDL Binding Type and JMS resources configuration.